# Lazy initialization not working iPhone

Tags: objective-c, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

So I have a lot of custom objects that could contain a lot of data, or very little data depending on the user's input.  I obviously don't want to to create storage for a lot of data if only a little is needed.  So I heard about initialization and it sounds like exactly what I want; I just can't get it to work.  Here is an example of one of my attempts:

```
@synthesize name;

...

- (NSString *)name {
    if (!name) name = [[NSString alloc] init];
    return name;
}
```

and then somewhere else

```
myObject.name = localName;
```

If I `alloc` and `init` myObject's name in its initializer then this works fine.  However, when I try the above lazy initialization, the object's name becomes `nil` after trying to set it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is ARC on? Is this for iOS 5/4, or is it manual reference counting?

Comment: Yes ARC is on, and this is for iOS 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@property (strong) NSString *name;

@synthesize name = _name;

- (NSString *)name {
    if (!_name) {
        _name = [[NSString alloc] init];
        ...
    }
    return _name;
}
```

Comment: Do I use this instead of my getter, or do I need to implement both?

Comment: @Garrett, you access this by doing self.name whenever you need it

Comment: This isn't functionally different from what OP had in the question -- if no variable name is specified, `@synthesize` creates it with the same name as the property. Can you explain why you think this will help?

Comment: @JoshCaswell That is exactly what I thought when I was writing it, which is why I didn't try it before asking the question.  However for some this reason this works and my code doesn't.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I am not sure. I read the question, read that his wasn't working, so I typed up the implementation I always use. It seemed to work for the OP, so either there is something we are both not seeing or there is something else. I think perhaps the OP wasn't using the self.name accessor method and maybe was just using 'name'

Comment: @Garrett: Are you also overriding the setter?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Nowhere in my object did I access its name other than in the getter, so I never used `self.name`.  And no I have not overridden the setter

Comment: @coneybeare Do you mean that I should have used `self.name` in my getter? Rather than just `name`.

Comment: I don't know what i was thinking - lol. looking back on my comments from late last night I must have been smoking crack. I don't know why this is any different for you, but I am glad to hear you got it working.